# Errors when compiling Elsevier's cas-dc-template on texmaker using texlive 2017/Debian

Tags: pdftex, ubuntu, texlive-2017

I downloaded [this](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/promis_misc/JESTCH_Templates.rar) template from Elsevier. Tried to compile it. On the first attempt, I get the following Error:

```
! Use of \@xfootnotenext doesn't match its definition. And it says from Line 172.
```

On next attempts, I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.\\ ->\let \reserved@e\relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserv... ...r the final layout}...
```

Am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Texmaker and TexLive 2017/Debian. What could be wrong?
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The `cas-dc` document class hasn't been around that long, and initially -- say, 3 to 4 years ago -- was quite buggy. It's been fixed up significantly, though, over the past year or so. Any chance you could update your TeX distribution and thereby the version of `cas-dc` your document gets to work with?

Comment: hello, tried to up-date it using instructions provided at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227684/installing-the-latest-texlive-via-command-line-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-virtual-machi  
but the error persists.

Comment: any more update suggestions?

Comment: ok, updating to texlive 2021 finally enabled me to compile the template with no issues. But it came with side effects such as not being able to convert eps files to pdfs when run within texmaker, Now am struggling with texmaker configurations responsible for that. otherwise. thanks :).